# Create Google Chrome extension package without specified files

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Right now to create an extension with Google Chrome Extensions page we select a directory that contains created extension and it generates `.crx` file.

The problem is that it contains all files from this directory - for example, all docs, asset drafts, etc.

Is it possible to create some blacklist to ignore specified files like `*.psd, *.pdf, docs/* ...` ?

Comment: just open the crx file and delete some of it's contents?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the command line program "zip", which could be found in cygwin if you're on windows, or is likely present on OSX, and easy to install if you're using linux.

```
zip package.zip -r * -x package.sh -x *.git* -x "*.*~" -x "*.pdf" docs/* "*.psd"
```

Comment: Or you could instead give the list of files you *do* want to include: `zip -r packaged.zip src/*.js src/manifest.json img/*.png img/*.jpg`. However, it seems that the question is really about creating `.crx` files which are kind of like zip files but not quite. It seems that you have to use `chrome://extensions` to do that or `\chrome.exe --enable-apps --pack- 
extension=<path\to\app\folder>`. Either way don't let you pick which files you want and which you don't. @hsz, you'd need to write your own script and move files around.

Comment: [.CRX files are special, signed, ZIP archives](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx), containing the author's public key and the extension signature. Simply zipping up some files won't create that kind of a ZIP archive.

Answer (score 3):

The Chromium team decided [not to implement a manifest (or similar mechanism) for including only the desired files in a .CRX](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=314360#c10).

The recommended workflow is to have a build step that outputs only the needed files in a `dist` directory, and to create the CRX from that directory. This is [common practice for JavaScript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730882/what-is-the-role-of-src-and-dist-folders).

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

I have created a `.crxignore` custom ignore file, like this:

```
.*
Makefile
*.md
bin
```

> It is made for zip command! It is different than `.gitignore`. You can't add comments eg! See documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip , look for `--exclude` word.

Now you can create a zip without ignred files:

```sh
$ zip -qr -9 -X .out/out.zip . -x@.crxignore
#                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ using ignore file
```

After that I can convert `zip` to `crx` file with this go script: https://github.com/mmadfox/go-crx3 You have to build it with `go build -o out/crx3 crx3/main.go` command (you may get missing mod errors, but there will be the commands what you have to run). --> you can move your `out/crx3` to where you want. Eg: `[project]/bin/crx3`.

> I haven't tried, maybe `chrome` command also can convert `zip` to `crx`.

You have to generate a private key:

```sh
$ bin/crx3 keygen .out/key.pem
```

#### Final `Makefile`

```
build:
    rm -f .out/out.zip
    zip -qr -9 -X .out/out.zip . -x@.crxignore
    bin/crx3 pack .out/out.zip -p .out/key.pem -o .out/out.crx
```

Build process:

```sh
$ make build
# --> build the .out/out.crx file
```