# What is the difference between build and dist folder?

Tags: javascript, deployment, gruntjs, gulp, webpack

As far as I know `/dist` is for production environments. It contains uglified and similar files. But why do we need a `/build` folder ?

Comment: no,man……I saw that question,but it ask src and dist folder,not the same

Comment: To clarify - The answer that you accepted points to the same link as the one that I had shared. And in his answer, build means the same as src.

Comment: Thanks,I've canceled,so what exactly diffs build and dist?

Comment: "build" means the same as "dist" or "dest". That is why i said it is a duplicate question.

Comment: I've see this code in a project,
`path: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './dist' : './build','`
it seems they are different

Comment: in most cases, "dist" means "build". you have to understand what the programmer is trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: Dist - for production minified files.
Build - for additional files you create during build, i.e. test reports.

But actually this is matter of style, not something deep.

Comment: I believe this question is a candidate for re-opening.  There are differences between all three of the directories mentioned: "build", "src", and "dist".  Daniel's answer described the difference as asked by OP and also linked to a similar, but not duplicate, question as context.  For example, it is quite common for a "build" directory to contain the output of Babel compilation, yet not be minified.

Comment: @alanning I think you are right. This is not about the difference between src and dist - I start a reopen vote.

Answer (score 39):

Dist is for distribution and contains minified code. Build contains code that is not minified and not ready for production deployment.

Check this link…
[What is the role of src and dist folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730882/what-is-the-role-of-src-and-dist-folders)

Comment: But create-react-app builds into `build` by default and that code is minified, right?