# Why some websites are not automatable using Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried automating https://www.westernunion.com/global-service/track-transfer web page but couldn't figure out why website is not navigating to next page.

My script is 
opening page -> Entering MTCN as 2587051083 -> Clicking on Continue button
but after click nothing shows up. While replicating the same steps manully works well. Is there any browser settings am I missing for these kind of sites? I am clueless

```
public static void main(String ar[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Study\\selenium-java-2.48.2\\selenium-2.48.2\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.westernunion.com/global-service/track-transfer");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='trackingNumber']")).sendKeys("2587051083");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='button-track-transfer']")).click();
        }
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please let me know your thoughts. Also please remove your downvote.

Comment: interesting, for some reason it cannot create session to get `sessionId` try using firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On  `https://www.westernunion.com/global-service/track-transfer` web page to send a *character sequece* within the *tracking field* I have made some minor modification to your own code inducing *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and then invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Continue** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class westernunion {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
          opt.addArguments("start-maximized");
          opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
          WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(opt);
          driver.get("https://www.westernunion.com/global-service/track-transfer");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.new-field.form-control.tt-mtcn.ng-pristine.ng-valid-mask"))).sendKeys("2587051083");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block.background-color-teal.remove-margin#button-track-transfer")).click();
      }
  }
  ```

It seems the `click()` does happens and the **spinner** becomes visible for a while but the search is interrupted and on inspecting the *webpage* you will find that some of the `<script>` tag and `<link>` tag refers to *css* having keyword **dist**. As an example:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/wucom/dist/20181210075630/css/responsive_css.min.css">`
- `<script src="/content/wucom/dist/20181210075630/js/js-bumblebee.js"></script>`
- `<link ng-if="trackTransferVm.trackTransferData.newTrackTransfer || trackTransferVm.trackTransferData.isRetail" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/wucom/dist/20181210075630/css/main.min.css" class="ng-scope" style="">`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Distil detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, I am also able to enter text and click on button though script but issue comes after clicking Continue button. Are you able to navigate to next page?

Comment: What I am looking is for the next page.... Any ways thanks a lot for your effort and time. Have a great day.

Comment: @Nakul Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: i have gone through the links and seems we cant automate those protected websites. Any ways thanks a lot for the detailed description/links.