# Clicking on Get Data button for Monthly Settlement Statistics on nseindia.com doesn't fetch results using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from [here](http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_monthly_statistics.htm").

By clicking on the capital market and 2019-20 year. I want to click on Get data.

I have used following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=chrome_options)

driver.get( nse_cash_keystats_page )


 driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='h_filetype']/option[text()='Capital Market ']" ).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='yearField']/option[text()='2019-2020']" ).click()

     downloadButton=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@type="image"][@src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif"]')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", downloadButton)
```

By using the above code, I am able to click on Get DATA. But it is not showing output.

Please help me.Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I took your code added a few tweaks and ran the test as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_monthly_statistics.htm')
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"select#h_filetype")))).select_by_visible_text("Capital Market ")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"select#yearField")))).select_by_visible_text("2019-2020")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.getdata-button#get[type='image'][src^='/common/images/btn-get-data.gif']"))).click()
  ```

---

### Observation

Similar to your observation, I have hit the same roadblock with no results as follows:

[image: nseindia_Monthly_Statement]

---

### Deep Dive

It seems the `click()` on the element with text as **Get Data** does happens. But while inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* you will find that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **akam**. As an example:

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www1.nseindia.com/akam/11/52349752" defer=""></script>`
- `<noscript><img src="https://www1.nseindia.com/akam/11/pixel_52349752?a=dD01ZDZiMTA5OGQ0MDljYTYxN2RjMjc3MzBlN2YwMDQ0NjlkZDNiNTMzJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

---

### Bot Manager

As per the article [Bot Manager - Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf):

[image: akamai_detection]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that the request for the data is detected as being performed by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the response is blocked.

---

### References

A couple of documentations:

- [Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/product-brief/bot-manager-product-brief.pdf)
- [Bot Manager : Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the similar problem with selenium and python. So I gave puppeteer a try if its selenium specific problem. even with raw puppeteer it was showing the same problem. i click get data button and blank box appear with console showing unauthorized access error. i knew akamai was causing this problem but qs. was how to fight that. so here is puppeteer script that i use to options data and bypass akamai. change it to suit your needs.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

async function nse(dates) {
    let launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', // because we are using puppeteer-core so we must define this option
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    };
    console.log(dates)
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // set viewport and user agent (just in case for nice viewing)
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36');

    // go to the target web
    await page.goto('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm');
    await page.select('#instrumentType', 'OPTIDX')
    await page.select('#symbol', 'NIFTY')
    await page.select('#year', '2020')
    await page.select('#expiryDate', `${dates[0]}`)
    await page.select('#optionType', 'CE')
    await page.waitForSelector('#rdDateToDate');
    let button = 'input[id="rdDateToDate"]';
    await page.evaluate((button) => document.querySelector(button).click(), button);
    // await page.select('#dateRange', '3month')
    await page.waitForSelector('#fromDate');
    await page.$eval('#fromDate', (el,date1) => el.value = date1, dates[1]);
    await page.waitForSelector('#toDate');
    await page.$eval('#toDate', (el,date2) => el.value = date2,dates[2]);
    let selector = 'input[class="getdata-button"]';
    await page.evaluate((selector) => document.querySelector(selector).click(), selector);
    await page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('.download-data-link') && document.querySelector('.download-data-link').clientHeight != 0");
    const btnNext = await page.$('.download-data-link');
    await page.waitFor(3000);
    await btnNext.click();
    await browser.close()
}


async function input_dates(input) {
    var dates = []
    for (let i = 0; i < input[0].length; i++) {
        dates.push([input[0][i], input[1][i], input[2][i]])

    }
    return dates

}
var data = [['30-01-2020', '27-02-2020', '26-03-2020', '30-04-2020', '28-05-2020'],//expiry date array
['01-Jan-2020', '01-Feb-2020', '01-Mar-2020', '01-Apr-2020', '01-May-2020'],//start date array
['30-Jan-2020', '27-Feb-2020', '26-Mar-2020', '30-Apr-2020', '28-May-2020']]//end date array

input_dates(data).then(async dates => {
    dates.forEach(async el =>{
        nse(el)
    } )
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

this downloads the data in your default download directory.