# Selenium code to download a file from a link not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have written the following code to download a file from the URL: https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/oi-spurts every 1 min. However, I have not been successful in getting it to work. I am seeing the Selenium is opening up a new tab instead of showing the default pop up when a link is clicked. Hoping to have someone help me out with this.

```
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DOWNLOAD_URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/oi-spurts"
DOWNLOAD_PATH = "/Users/myuser/Downloads/"


class SeleniumDriver(object):

    def __init__(self, download_path=DOWNLOAD_PATH):
        logging.debug("Selenium DEBUG")
        self.__download_path = download_path

    def initiate_download(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')  # For Linux systems
        # chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
        chrome_options.add_argument("disable-web-security")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--download.default_directory={self.__download_path}')

        # Create a Chrome WebDriver instance
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

        try:
            # Navigate to the website where the file is located
            driver.get(DOWNLOAD_URL)
            import time
            time.sleep(10)
            download_link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xlsdownload a")
            print(download_link)
            print(dir(download_link))
            download_link.click()
            # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_link)
            #download_link[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

            # Perform actions on the website to trigger the file download
            # ...

            # Wait for the file to download (you may need to adjust the sleep time)
            time.sleep(5)

        finally:
            # Close the browser session
            driver.quit()


    __slots__ = (
        "__download_path",
    )
```

The error I see every time is :
[image: Error]

Comment: looks like the response was cutoff during the transfer... (malformed response) You might reconsider downloading something every minute.  It may be overloading the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was also working along the same line few years back. I realized at that time that NSE websites have active trackers that block bots trying to crawl through their websites. Refer to this discussion on stack overflow, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do) might help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).