# How can I scrape a website without getting detected and bypassing reCAPTCHA using selenium webdriver through Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, recaptcha, webdriver-w3c-spec

I know the webscraping and I have taken the data from different website and I am using python language and selenium webdriver chrome. But I call a website it is open front page and then I click or go any other page then website restrict me and website know that I am using automated chrome.

Comment: Probably the number of requests per second.
Be aware that scrapping is most of the time illegal and tey can ban your ip easily, you should make some sleeps each time you want to scrap

Comment: I have never used Selenium, if it is possible try adding a User-Agent to the request.

Comment: I am using sleep but it is not effecting the website. I think website capture automated google chrome request on first time and it do not allow to do any thing

Answer (score 2):

This may be because the website uses reCAPTCHA v3, which "allows you to verify if an interaction is legitimate without any user interaction". This means that they can identify if you are not a human without asking you to check the famous "I'm not a robot" box. That box is used in the former version of reCAPTCHA, v2.

Read more about reCAPTCHA here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions

I don't think it's possible to work around this with Selenium. And, as was already mentioned, web scraping is often illegal.

Comment: Main problem is how to call from automated chrome that did not capture by website that it is not automated chrome

Answer (score 0):

These days, *websites* can detect your program as a **BOT** pretty easily. Currently *Google* have *4(four)* [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) to choose and implement from when creating a new site.

- *reCAPTCHA v3*
- *reCAPTCHA v2 ("I'm not a robot" Checkbox)*
- *reCAPTCHA v2 (Invisible reCAPTCHA badge)*
- *reCAPTCHA v2 (Android)*

### Solution

However there are some generic approaches to avoid getting detected while web-scraping:

- The first and foremost attribute a website can determine your script/program is through your **monitor size**. So it is recommended **not** to use the conventional [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- If you need to send multiple requests to a website keep on changing the **User Agent** on each request. Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254)
- To simulate *human like* behavior you may require to slow down the script execution even beyond [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) and [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) inducing `time.sleep(secs)`. Here you can find a detailed discussion on [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)

### Outro

See:

- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)