# Selenium and non-headless browser keeps asking for Captcha

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, captcha, webdriver-w3c-spec

I was running into an issue in which one of our sites kept asking for captcha in headless mode in a browser in the cloud, so I switched it to non headless, so I could enter the captcha myself, and I thought the next times it would work, perhaps because some cookies would be stored already, but it didn't even though I entered the captcha several times.

Also it's worth mentioning that it runs just fine locally in whatever mode, and it also runs well in the cloud for the non automated version, but as soon as as I run l it there with Selenium in whatever mode it keeps asking for the captcha. Any ideas what might be happening and ideas on the solution are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the discussion entitled [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835) we have discussed about some generic approaches to avoid getting detected while web-scraping. Let's deep dive.

---

### Headless Browser

A headless browser is a browser that can be used without a graphical interface. It can be controlled programmatically to automate tasks, such as doing tests or taking screenshots of webpages.

---

### Why detect headless browser?

As per [@AntoineVastel](https://antoinevastel.com/bot%20detection/2017/08/05/detect-chrome-headless.html), headless browsers are used to automate malicious tasks. The most common cases are web scraping, increase advertisement impressions or look for vulnerabilities on a website.

Until an year ago, one of the most popular headless browser was PhantomJS. Since it is built on the Qt framework, it exhibits many differences compared to most popular browsers. It was possible to detect PhantomJS using some browser fingerprinting techniques. Since version 59, Google released a headless version of its Chrome browser. Unlike PhantomJS, it is based on a vanilla Chrome, and not on an external framework, making its presence more difficult to detect. So there are likely other ways to detect Chrome headless.

---

### Detecting Chrome Headless

- **User agent**: The user agent attribute is commonly used to detect the OS as well as the browser of the user. With Chrome version 59 it has the following value:

  ```
  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
  ```

  - A check for the presence of *Chrome headless* can be done through:

    ```
    if (/HeadlessChrome/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        console.log("Chrome headless detected");
    }
    ```
- **Plugins**: **`navigator.plugins`** returns an array of plugins present in the browser. Typically, on Chrome we find default plugins, such as `Chrome PDF viewer` or `Google Native Client`. On the opposite, in headless mode, the array returned contains **no** plugin.

  - A check for the presence of *Plugins* can be done through:

    ```
    if(navigator.plugins.length == 0) {
        console.log("It may be Chrome headless");
    }
    ```
- **Languages**: In Chrome two Javascript attributes enable to obtain languages used by the **`user: navigator.language`** and **`navigator.languages`**. The first one is the language of the browser UI, while the second one is an array of string representing the user’s preferred languages. However, in headless mode, **`navigator.languages`** returns an **empty** string.

  - A check for the presence of *Languages* can be done through:

    ```
    if(navigator.languages == "") {
         console.log("Chrome headless detected");
    }
    ```
- **WebGL**: WebGL is an API to perform 3D rendering in an HTML canvas. With this API, it is possible to query for the vendor of the graphic driver as well as the renderer of the graphic driver. With a vanilla Chrome and Linux, we can obtain the following values for renderer and vendor: **`Google SwiftShader`** and **`Google Inc.`**. In headless mode, we can obtain **`Mesa OffScreen`**, which is the technology used for rendering without using any sort of window system and **`Brian Paul`**, which is the program that started the open source Mesa graphics library.

  - A check for the presence of *WebGL* can be done through:

    ```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

    var debugInfo = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
    var vendor = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL);
    var renderer = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);

    if(vendor == "Brian Paul" && renderer == "Mesa OffScreen") {
        console.log("Chrome headless detected");
    }
    ```
  - Not all Chrome headless will have the same values for vendor and renderer. Others keep values that could also be found on non headless version. However, **`Mesa Offscreen`** and **`Brian Paul`** indicates the presence of the headless version.
- **Browser features**: Modernizr library enables to test if a wide range of HTML and CSS features are present in a browser. The only difference we found between Chrome and headless Chrome was that the latter did not have the hairline feature, which detects support for **`hidpi/retina hairlines`**.

  - A check for the presence of *hairline feature* can be done through:

    ```
    if(!Modernizr["hairline"]) {
        console.log("It may be Chrome headless");
    }
    ```
- **Missing image**: The last on our list also seems to be the most robust, comes from the dimension of the image used by Chrome in case an image cannot be loaded. In case of a vanilla Chrome, the image has a width and height that depends on the zoom of the browser, but are different from zero. In a headless Chrome, the image has a width and an height equal to zero.

  - A check for the presence of *Missing image* can be done through:

    ```
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "http://iloveponeydotcom32188.jg";
    image.setAttribute("id", "fakeimage");
    body.appendChild(image);
    image.onerror = function(){
        if(image.width == 0 && image.height == 0) {
        console.log("Chrome headless detected");
        }
    }
    ```

These are some of the crucial factors why headless browsers are more prone to get detected.

---

### Outro

- [Detecting PhantomJS Based Visitors](https://blog.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/22/detecting-phantomjs-based-visitors/)
- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)

Answer (score -3):

So how captcha works is, based on the speed you do actions it will trigger a sort of flag that will notify the server that you are either A) Trying to hack the web page or B) Automating it. This will almost always spawn up a captcha instance. To date, there is no way to handle captcha. If this is a environment your company has developed, you can ask the devs to turn captcha off for on a staging environment with a different URL. This is the ideal situation, But if this is an external site then there is nothing you can do about it.