# Why I cannot scrape all the data from Zillow?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, zillow

I'm trying to scrape the data from Zillow (prices) as a practice with Python and I'm not getting the data complete.

This is my code

```
from jobEntryBot import JobEntryBot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pprint import pprint
import time
import requests
URL_ZILLOW = r"https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-123.4663871665039%2C%22east%22%3A-121.7744926352539%2C%22south%22%3A37.03952097286371%2C%22north%22%3A38.19687379258651%7D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A9%7D"

header = {
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/511.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/139.3.3.3 Safari/312.311',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
data = requests.get(headers=header, url=URL_ZILLOW)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
selector_for_prices = ".gMDnGj span"
prices = soup.select(selector_for_prices)
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

I try this but **only get 9 prices ** not all the 40 something prices on the webpage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPTxP.png)

I've tried using other functions like soup.find_all() but it doesn't work. I've tried even using selenium.
If I inspect the Zillow page and use the selector I use in the code it works but not in my code.
Pd: I changed the user_agent for the code I show fyi

Comment: The cards are rendered based on the scroll height. To get the rest of them you will have to scroll all the way down.

Comment: Also, is that correct css selector? Aren't the prices in the `span` tag with `data-test="property-card-price"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the website has web-detection capabilities, you will first need find a way to avoid detection. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56529616/13684789) contains a comprehensive list of methods to avoid detection.

It may also be worth looking into the APIs Zillow offers, as it does not seem like there will be a simple way to scrape their website. But if your just doing fun or as a personal learning experience, then it definitely worth take some time to figure out the best approach to scrape Zillow.

Comment: How did u get to that conclusion? I read that maybe the problem is solved with a rotating residential proxy because using selenium Zillow responds with a catpcha of "press and hold". 
I appretiate the help

Comment: Just ran `driver.get(url)` a couple times and I got the captcha test, so my answer won't work. A work around like the one you mentioned might work, but I recommend first figuring out how the website is detecting bots. Knowing that will help you determine the best approach to avoid detection.

Comment: Also, it may be helpful looking at the requests the website makes. You may be able to get the data you want by making the appropriate requests yourself. This [article](https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html) goes over the basics of doing so in Chrome.