# Bypass detecting Bot website with undetected selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I use undetected_chromedriver and other options to chrome driver but still block in this website(https://ceo.baemin.com). It occurs the blocking problem when I use headless mode in option. please save my time. I'm tring to bypass it for 3 days.

you need to install with pip
fake_useragent, undetected_chromedriver, selenium_stealth, selenium, etc...

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

options = uc.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = uc.Chrome( options = options,enable_cdp_events=True,incognito=True,headless=True,use_subprocess=True)

stealth(driver,
        vendor="Google Inc. ",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="intel Inc. ",
        renderer= "Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )


options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')


driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
driver.execute_script("window.chrome=true")
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {get: function() {return[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];},});")

driver.get('https://ceo.baemin.com')

print(driver.page_source)
```

Bypass detecting Bot website with undetected selenium

Comment: Using puppeteer the website is not getting blocked try once

Comment: I tried it in CentOS7 and it occurs pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly error. I can't solve it with pyppeteer.

Comment: I am not talking about pyppeteer if you are familiar with javascript try puppeteer package in nodejs. Just change necessary properties like web drivers and touch point etc it will be able to scrape.

Comment: Rotate proxies and keep changing the user-agents. If you are looking for a detailed explanation, [Check this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-webdriver-that-is-not-detectable/56529616#56529616)