# Selenium Chrome gets detected

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a bot for https://www.phonehouse.nl/verlengchecker . But when I use Chrome it gets detected. When I use Firefox it only opens the page and doesn't do anything. I tried it on Arch linux and Windows result is the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

capabilities = {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions':  {
    'useAutomationExtension': False,
    'forceDevToolsScreenshot': True,
    'args': ['--start-maximized', '--disable-infobars']
  }
}    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(capabilities=capabilities)
def control(provider, number, day, month, year, post, email, street):
    
    driver.get("https://www.phonehouse.nl/verlengchecker")
    sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='businessSelectBoxIt']").send_keys(provider) #provider
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='msisdn']").send_keys(number) #number
```

Comment: Could it be because of your fast requests?  Also, what is your question?

Comment: There’s no question?

Comment: I think the question is how to stop chrome-selenium from being detected

Comment: So...is the problem your firefox version of the above isn't working?

Comment: Could you clarify what the website returns when it detects Selenium?

Comment: When it detects selenium it says refresh the page. It even starts to say it whem  I make my first request. So it's not about speed. I also change my IP address so it's not an IP ban either.

Comment: When I tried to open this page using selenium, it worked. So, before trying further automation in that webpage with your code, just try to only open the webpage. You'll know if the issue is being raised by 'get' request or by further codes.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis was in the right direction. [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* can easily get detected by the [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha).

### Deep Dive

If you access the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) you will find the existance of the [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123142/selenium-and-non-headless-browser-keeps-asking-for-captcha/56136820#56136820).

[image: invisible_recaptcha]

---

### Conclusion

Recaptcha can easily detect [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated *Browsing Context*.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)

However there are some generic ways to avoid detection and you can find a detailed discussion in [How to bypass Google captcha with Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-to-bypass-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python/58876531#58876531)

---

### Outro

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "provider" space isn't an input so you can't use `send_keys`,

But you can use this for the number:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
def control(number):
    driver.get("https://www.phonehouse.nl/verlengchecker")
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="msisdn"]').send_keys(number)
control("000")
```