# How do I hide the fact I'm using a bot?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, captcha

So for my python selenium script I have to complete a lot of Captcha's. I noticed that when I get the Captcha's on my regular browser they're much easier and quicker. Is there a way for me to hide the fact that I'm using a web automation bot so I get the easier Captcha's?

I already tried randomizing the User Agent but to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a generic perspective there are no proven ways to hide the fact that you are using a [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven web automation bot.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)

However at certain times [modifying the `navigator.webdriver` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904) helps to prevent detection.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there a way to use Selenium WebDriver without informing the document that it is controlled by WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862023/is-there-a-way-to-use-selenium-webdriver-without-informing-the-document-that-it/52900495#52900495)
- [Selenium Chrome gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973702/selenium-chrome-gets-detected/62983883#62983883)
- [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your website and inspect the page. Then go to the network tab and select `Network`. Reload the page and the select the webpage you are accessing from the list. If you scroll down, you can see the user agent that your browser is using to access the page. Use that user agent in your scraper to exactly mimick your browser.