# Dynamic dropdown doesn't populate with auto suggestions on https://www.nseindia.com/ when values are passed using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, autosuggest, akamai

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Workspace/Development/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions')
inputbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/input[2]')
inputbox.send_keys("Reliance")
```

I'm trying to scrape the table from this [website](https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions) that would appear after you key in the company name in the textfield above it. The attached code block works well with such similar drop-downs of a normal google search and wolfram website, but when i run my script on the required website, that essentially just inputs the required text in the textfield - the dropdown shows 'No Records Found', whereas, when done manually it works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I executed your test adding a few tweaks and ran the test as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver        
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='Corporate_Actions_equity']//input[@placeholder='Company Name or Symbol']"))).send_keys("Reliance")
  ```
- Observation: Similar to your observation, I have hit the same roadblock with no results as follows:

[image: nseindia]

---

### Deep Dive

It seems the `click()` on the element with text as **Get Data** does happens. But while inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* you will find that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **akam**. As an example:

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.nseindia.com/akam/11/3b383b75" defer=""></script>`
- `<noscript><img src="https://www.nseindia.com/akam/11/pixel_3b383b75?a=dD02ZDMxODU2ODk2YTYwODA4M2JlOTlmOGNkZTY3Njg4ZWRmZjE4YmMwJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

---

### Bot Manager

As per the article [Bot Manager - Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf):

[image: akamai_detection]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that the request for the data is detected as being performed by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the response is blocked.

---

### References

A couple of documentations:

- [Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/product-brief/bot-manager-product-brief.pdf)
- [Bot Manager : Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! I understood i'd have to change my whole approach to scrape what i wanted from the website and on the way learnt new things. If interested - I got a hold of this while inspecting the JS files --> (https://www1.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/getCorpActions.jsp?symbol=SBIN&Industry=&ExDt=More%20than%2024%20Months&exDt=More%20than%2024%20Months&recordDt=&bcstartDt=&industry=&CAType=SPLIT)
The JSON format then made it easy to get what i wanted.

Comment: useautomationextension is deprecated now. There does not seem to be any automationextension in the chromedriver source anymore. What did they do and how to bypass the detection now?