# How can i grab data from a NSE chart with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get data showing on the chart when I move the mouse.
[NSE chart Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyDMM.png)

Comment: and where is your code ? If page uses JavaScript then you may need Selenium or you should check what url uses JavaScript to read data and use it to get data.

Comment: you could add link to this page.

Comment: examples from other questions for nseindia.com but I don't know if there is example for page with chart: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/nseindia.com%20-%20requests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic dropdown doesn't populate with auto suggestions on https://www.nseindia.com/ when values are passed using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457093/dynamic-dropdown-doesnt-populate-with-auto-suggestions-on-https-www-nseindia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chart read data from urls

https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=BERGEPAINTEQN

https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=BERGEPAINTEQN&preopen=true

and you can get it with `requests`

This page needs header `User-Agent` but it can be even short `'Mozilla/5.0'`.

```
import requests
import datetime

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=BERGEPAINTEQN'
#url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex?index=BERGEPAINTEQN&preopen=true'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# --- response ---

#print(r.status_code)

data = r.json()

print('name:', data['name'])
print('identifier:', data['identifier'])
print('close price:', data['closePrice'])

prices = data['grapthData'][:10]

for item in prices:
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(item[0]/1000)
    value = item[1]
    print(dt, value)
```

Result

```
name: BERGEPAINT
identifier: BERGEPAINTEQN
close price: 551.45

2020-08-11 09:15:00 553.7
2020-08-11 09:15:01 553.7
2020-08-11 09:15:02 553
2020-08-11 09:15:03 553.95
2020-08-11 09:15:04 553.9
2020-08-11 09:15:05 553.6
2020-08-11 09:15:06 553.85
2020-08-11 09:15:07 553.35
2020-08-11 09:15:08 553.35
2020-08-11 09:15:09 553.35
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, It's working excellent without a single error.