# Selenium: access denied

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape some data from LV website with Selenium and keep getting 'Access Denied' screen once 'sign in' button clicked. I feel like there is a protection against this because all seems to be working fine when I do the same manually. Oddly, I need to click 'sign in' button twice to be able to sign in manually.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/mylv')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ucm-wrapper']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ucm-button ucm-button--default ucm-choice__yes']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id('loginloginForm').send_keys('xxx@xxx.com')
driver.find_element_by_id ('passwordloginForm').send_keys('xxxxxx')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginSubmit_').click()
```

Error:

```
You don't have permission to access "http://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/mylv;jsessionid=xxxxxxx.front61-prd?" on this server.
```

Is there a way to login with Selenium and bypass this?

Comment: .double_click() ?

Comment: sorry, for not being clear. i get 'access denied' after single click with Selenium. When do it manually nothing happens, if i click once and logs in after second click only.

Comment: it seems the site detects that it's a bot. I 'm afraid it might not be possible so simply

Comment: Maybe you should try adding lots of time.sleep in between to clone human like behaviour. Nowadays site detect how fast you type, how fast you scroll etc.

Comment: If you have some patience i'm gonna try for it.

Comment: i have already tried adding 2s between adding user, then 2s for pass and then 2s for submit but it didn't help. I get similar 'access denied' message when Selenium does .refresh()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I had posted this question but if anyone is interested below are the steps I've taken to solve the problem.

1. Open `chromedriver.exe` in hex editor, find the string `$cdc` and replace with something else of the same length. Then save and run modified binary. Read more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/7435394) and the replies to it.
2. Selenium python code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                                                                     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                                                                     'Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'})
```

Comment: Could you extend on what does the script exactly do?, works but I'd like to understand why

Comment: I needed to periodically check whether one rare bag is in stock but the website had some sort of anti-bot/anti-selenium script which prevented me from doing that. The steps above allowed to overcome the problem.

Comment: @Mudyla Hi looks like you know your stuff. If you are interested in working with me on a good and small project, please email me: crew.gladiator@gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

I took your code added a few tweaks and ran the test as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  driver.get('https://secure.louisvuitton.com/eng-gb/mylv')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accept and Continue']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='loginloginForm']"))).send_keys("Mudyla@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwordloginForm']").send_keys('Mudyla')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginSubmit_']").click()
  ```

---

### Observation

Similar to your observation, I have hit the same roadblock with no results as follows:

[image: AccessDenied]

---

### Deep Dive

It seems the `click()` on <kbd>Sign In</kbd> does happens. But while inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* you will find that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **akam**. As an example:

- `akam-sw.js install script version 1.3.3 "serviceWorker"in navigator&&"find"in[]&&function()`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.louisvuitton.com/akam/11/7f0e2ae6" defer=""></script>`
- `<noscript><img src="https://secure.louisvuitton.com/akam/11/pixel_7f0e2ae6?a=dD0xOWNjNTRjMmMxYzdmNmMwZjI0NTUwOGZmZDM5ZTQzMWQ5NjI5ZmIwJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by [**Bot Manager**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp) an advanced bot detection service provided by [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/) and the response gets **blocked**.

---

### Bot Manager

As per the article [Bot Manager - Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf):

[image: akamai_detection]

---

### Conclusion

So it can be concluded that the request for the data is detected as being performed by [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance and the response is blocked.

---

### References

A couple of documentations:

- [Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/product-brief/bot-manager-product-brief.pdf)
- [Bot Manager : Foundations](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/akamai/akamai-bot-manager-training-overview-and-agenda.pdf)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevant discussions:

- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457093/dynamic-dropdown-doesnt-populate-with-auto-suggestions-on-https-www-nseindia/62457673#62457673)
- [Clicking on Get Data button for Monthly Settlement Statistics on nseindia.com doesn't fetch results using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I added the following line just after launching a driver:

```
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```